# Why is a float digit rounded in django list_display

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to show one field, which is a result of division two int variables, in my django admin list. I'm expecting to see float digit like `0.95` but i've got 0, for example. Why?

My Model:

```
class Flat(models.Model):
    flat_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Цена квартиры')
    flat_prediction_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Прогноз')

    def show_price(self):
        return unicode(self.flat_price) + u" тыс. руб."

    def show_accuracy(self):
        if self.flat_prediction_price is None:
            return float(999)
        else:
            result = self.flat_price/self.flat_prediction_price                    return round(result, 2)
```

and Admin:

```
class FlatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Flat
    inlines = [NeedInline]
    list_display = ('show_price','show_accuracy')
```

Comment: Try `result = float(self.flat_price) / self.flat_prediction_price`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As selchuk mentioned, if you do `float(self.flat_price) / self.flat_prediction_price` that will return you the floated result (and you can round from there).

What's happening with what you're doing now is that you're dividing an int by an int, which will give you an int result. You're then rounding after you have that int result, which won't round how you're wanting it to round since it is already just `0`. By diving a float by int (or can convert both to float) you'll get back a float result and can round that result.